# Grafana regex for transformation

Tags: regex, grafana

I'd like to use grafana to filter values by name:

This is an example of my keys and values:

```
disk_usage.root.dev.used 0 1608582030
disk_usage.root.dev.avail 7816 1608582030
disk_usage.root.dev.used_percentage 0 1608582030
disk_usage.root.run.used 147 1608582030
disk_usage.root.run.avail 1420 1608582030
disk_usage.root.run.used_percentage 10 1608582030
disk_usage.root.used 6930 1608582030
disk_usage.root.avail 214260 1608582030
disk_usage.root.used_percentage 4 1608582030
disk_usage.root.boot.efi.used 1 1608582030
disk_usage.root.boot.efi.avail 120 1608582030
disk_usage.root.boot.efi.used_percentage 1 1608582030
```

Now would like to show only those, whose name contains "_percentage".

I tried to use this:

```
/(_percentage)/
```

but this does not work.

However, if I do the negative lookup like

```
^((?!percentage).)*$
```

it shows all values - but not the ones, having "percentage" in it.

My question: How can I only show those values having "percentage" in it?

Comment: Try `.*_percentage.*`, or, if wildcards are suported, `*_percentage*`

Answer (score 2):

Use the following filter:

```
/.+_percentage/
```